# How to implement a transparent header on mobile view

Tags: html, css, header, transparent

I'm trying to implement a transparent header for mobile view like this: [image: clickup.com]

For comparison, my current header renders above my hero image and has a white background. It looks like this: [image: dasa.rf.gd]

What can I do to have my header render on top of the hero image with a transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

Change the background style of the header by adding `background: transparent;`

Answer (score 0):

well you can achieve this by setting the CSS's `background` attribute to `transparent` or `#0000`.
make sure you put this in a media query for only mobile screens.